# What actually cause quench cracking, non-uniform cooling or rapid cooling?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, steel, manufacturing-engineering, metallurgy

It’s well known that quenching most alloyed steels starting from AISI 4140 to high speed steels in water, brine , or sometimes oil will cause cracking and distortions.

In industry, oil quenching is sometimes replaced by molten salt, which is considered better than oil in decreasing crack probability and this advantageous, attributed to uniform cooling provided by salt baths, compared to other quenching mediums.

Cracks and distortions caused by water or brine quenching are usually attributed to rapid cooling, but sometimes they are attributed to non-uniform cooling caused by vapor blanket. That’s so confusing!!

It is expected to obtain uniform cooling by quenching steel in high concentration salt solution "nearly saturated solution" thanks to large amounts of ion particles which disturb vapor blanket, but these type of solutions will also have high cooling rates compared to oil. Such rapid cooling is usually attributed to be the of quench cracks in water quenching!

O1 steel can’t fully hardened in parts larger than 1 inch!

[image]

so my problem if it is safe to quench thick parts of such low hardenability steels in very high concentration salt solution which are expected to combining uniform cooling with relatively high speed cooling to fully harden thick parts of such low hardenability steel ?

Comment: What about cracks that develop through faults in the material...

Comment: "Hardenability of steels" formerly was about a one year /6 semester hour class ; I doubt it can be explained in a couple paragraphs.

Comment: It’s not about hardenability it’s about quenching. I have no issues with hardenability .

Comment: Are they not related?

Comment: If I wouldn’t change the grade to be used of course they are not related .

Comment: A fast cooling rate only causes cracks because you have temperature difference between the core and the surface, (similar to different areas with non-uniform cooling). The thicker the part the longer it takes for the core to cool and the greater temperature difference you have (increasing chance of cracking) as well as less hardening away from the surface. Another question is do you actually need a fully hardened part? A softer core can actually be beneficial in a lot of cases.

Comment: I read about something called "intensive quenching" and they say that extremely high cooling rate forms compressive stress in the surface thanks to very high thermal gradient and these compressive stresses exceeding tensile stress resulted from martensitic core expansion leading not only to prevent quench cracks but also to increase tool’s life .

Comment: Cracks are caused by internal stresses which are greater than the maximum stress. Internal stresses are created by uneven instantaneous temperature gradient. Keep in mind that quenching cools by removing heat from the outside surface. The inner mass of the object will always remain hotter. So the more rapid the quench, the higher the temperature gradient from outside to inside and the more stress. Obviously the material properties are also changing during the quench. But I believe the main source of stress during the quench is the temperature gradient from inside to outside.

Comment: Fourier's law of conduction implies that the faster the cooling, the more non-uniform the temperature and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question ; maybe.  O-1 tool steel has good hardenability ; the standard Jominy test showing HRC 60 two inches from the end ( austenitized at 1525 F). From experience with O-1 , cracking occurred in small parts ( less than 1/2" thick) when oil quenched from 1475 F , but when quenched into oil from 1600 F no cracking occurred. This was because the higher temperature produced retained austinite ; being relatively soft and ductile it prevented cracking. The same affect would occur with water quenching ( retained austenite). One would need to experiment with the best austenitizing temperature for each part configuration using a water quench. Double tempering will be needed as the retained austenite will mostly transform during the first temper. Heat-treated steels tend to crack and distort because of the stresses caused by the contraction and expansion: As the steel cools ( contraction) and transforms to martensite ( expansion), then continues cooling (contraction).

Comment: sorry but I can’t consider 60 Rc full hardening , full hardening meaning that the hardness both in the surface and the core are nearly equal. in our case we are talking about 64-67 Rc in the core of 4 inch O1 steel punch.

Comment: I read an article about causes of quench cracks and they say : "fine-needle or latent-leaf martensite formed
from fine-grained (no. 11) and ultrafine-grained
(no. 12–14) austenite has significantly higher potential of brittle strength of steel than the level of internal
stresses of any character (local tensile, compressive
stresses and so on). In this case, cracks did not appear
both immediately during quenching and upon
infinitely prolonged holding of parts after quenching."  

they mentioned also quenching fine grained U8A carbon steel in brine with
intense mixing without cracks !!

Comment: Quench cracking is caused primarily in steels by the martensite expansion occurring at different times at different depths .To learn about quench severity. harden-ability, tool steels , etc. I recommend American Society for Metals books.

Comment: "Intensive Quenching Systems: Engineering and Design" this the book I will read , it seems very non-conventional and really interesting.
they claims that very high cooling rate creating large enough compressive stress counteract tensile stresses resulted from martensite expansion so it actually suppressing cracks !

Comment: Like preventing water from expanding as it freezes into ice; It is going to require a lot of strength to contain the martensite expansion.